In T-SQL query, find duplicates in one column with unique values and display in another column
I have a table of aliases linked to values. I need to find duplicate aliases with unique record ids.
To explain better, here's the table:
ID    Alias     Value
---------------------
1     000123    3
2     000123    3
3     000234    4
4     000123    3
5     000345    5
6     000345    5

The result of a query on this table should be something to the effect of
ID    Alias     Value1    Value2
---------------------------------------
1     000123       3        3
2     000123       3
3     000234       4        4
4     000123       3
5     000345       5        5
6     000345       5     

I am currently using EXCEL to do the workaround:
=IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$F109889, $F109889)=1, $I109889, "")

Alias   --          Value1      Value2
---------------------------------------
16986   1231        2639.26     2639.26
16986   1231        2639.26 
16986   1231        2639.26 
16986   1231        2639.26 
16986   1231        2639.26 
16986   1231        2639.26 
16986   1231        2639.26 
16986   1231        2639.26 
16986   1231        2639.26 
16986   1231        2639.26 

But due to the # of records (around 200k rows), sometimes my laptop will hang for over an hour.
Are there any solutions out there that would work better?
I'm trying to do the report on SQL Server instead of in Excel.

Why is the extra value of  4 for 000234 comes from ? Will you have more than 1 row of duplicate ? How do you want the result like for such case ?

SELECT
  ID
  ,Alias
  ,Value1   = Value
  ,Value2   = IIF(COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY Alias 
                               ORDER BY ID 
                               ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) = 1
                  ,Value
                  ,NULL )
  ,Value2_2 = IIF(COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY Alias 
                               ORDER BY ID 
                               ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) = 1
                  ,FORMAT(Value,'0')
                  ,'' )
FROM (VALUES
 (1, '000123', 3)
,(2, '000123', 3)
,(3, '000234', 4)
,(4, '000123', 3)
,(5, '000345', 5)
,(6, '000345', 5)
)v(ID, Alias, Value)
ORDER BY ID


Tq! I got it to work with your help!!!

@Dale K Done, Just found out.
